# After creating a dataframe from an excel file, some columns are not readable by pandas functions

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I've created a dataframe from an Excel file correctly. I am creating a new column based on a condition, and this works:

```
df['sped_bin'] = np.where(df['SPED'] == 'Yes', 0, 1) 
print(df['sped_bin'])

0      1
1      1
2      1
3      0
4      1
```

However, on the same excel spreadsheet there are columns where the values are not recognized:

```
 df['gender_bin'] = np.where(df['Gender'] == 'Male', 0, 1) 
print(df['gender_bin'])


0      1
1      1
2      1
3      1
4      1
```

(I know there are other ways to turn 'yes/no', or 'gender' into binary. That is not relevant to my question.)

Something is different about the two columns in the excel file and I can't figure it out. Things I have tried:

1. Stripping all whitespace from the dataframe strings:

   df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)
2. Copying the formatting from the good column to the bad column in excel, resave, rerun.
3. Converting from .xls to .xlsx, and back again
4. Converting to csv file, then dataframe from that csv file.
5. Removing all formatting from all columns of the excel file.
6. Every single thing I could think of on the excel file.

Things that work that are too inefficient:

1. Typing in "Male" in the "SPED" column of the excel file, then copying that cell from the "SPED" column to the "Gender" column.
2. Copying the "SPED" column, renaming it "Gender", then hand typing "Male, Female..." in that column. (Please god no.)

The excel file is huge and is output from another program for which I do not have access/source code. How can I make the "Gender" column like the "SPED" column??? The problem is probably in the Excel document. Please help!

Comment: Have you tried selecting all rows where the df[df['Gender'] == 'Male'] condition should be true, and seeing what the output is? Same for selecting all rows where the condition should be false? That would help you check if the selection logic (and the df data) has been loaded correctly from your excel?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this basically checks the same thing in a different way. Your first way returns an empty data frame and the second way returns all rows. I also get the same results for 'Female', because it is not recognizing the strings in the columns. But that column is there when I print the dataframe, and the data type of the 'Gender' values is string. I'm losing my mind. So frustrating.

Comment: have you checked that gender hasn't got leading or trailing blanks or non printable chars? it doesn't seem to be an excel issue if converting to csv didn't solve it.

Comment: Thanks again, but yes I stripped everything. Mentioned in original post.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this:

```
np.where(df['Gender'].str.contains('Female'), 1, 0)
```

Comment: This is a great solution and worked! Thanks so much. I didn't have ".contains" in my toolbox. However, for those interested, the problem with the data in those Excel file columns was never solved.